# WPF How to make declaration into code?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I download a sample code from here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28306/Working-with-Checkboxes-in-the-WPF-TreeView

The sample code works fine. My questions is that I want to make this part of xaml into C# code.

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <!-- Load this specific theme because the Aero theme for CheckBox has issues. -->


      <Style x:Key="TreeViewItemStyle" TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsInitiallySelected, Mode=OneTime}" />
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.AcceptsReturn" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="dw:VirtualToggleButton.IsVirtualToggleButton" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="dw:VirtualToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsChecked}" />        
      </Style>

      <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
        x:Key="CheckBoxItemTemplate"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Mode=OneTime}"
        >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <!-- These elements are bound to a FooViewModel object. -->
          <CheckBox
            Focusable="False" 
            IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            />
          <ContentPresenter 
            Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneTime}" 
            Margin="2,0"
            />
        </StackPanel>
      </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that? 
Thanks,

Comment: You can do that as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990624/wpf-add-controls-from-code . Out of my curiosity, may I ask why you wan't to do that ?

Comment: if you need to use these in cs code, you don't need to port them to cs, you can just resolve the resource in cs. It' be much easier to maintain markup code in XAML

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to combine Thanks for the reply. I am trying to combine the VirtualToggleButton class and  FooViewModel into a custom control.