# Add WPF Controls Dynamically using Code

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and came across a situation where i think adding controls dynamically would be good.

But i don't know if there **is way to it dynamically using code**. I want to add following using Code

```
<WrapPanel Height="39">
      <TextBox Width="93" Margin="-1,5,0,0"></TextBox>
      <TextBox Width="76" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBox>
      <TextBox Width="70" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBox>
      <TextBox Width="70" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBox>
      <TextBox Width="127" Margin="0,5,0,0"></TextBox>
      <TextBox Width="100" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

I tried [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990624/wpf-add-controls-from-code) method,but it did not work

Comment: @bit I tried that method but it did not work,so i posted new question

Comment: Can you state what have you tried?

Comment: The code which you claim didn't work should work. Post your code which didn't work.

Comment: learn about DataTemplates , ItemsControl , ItemsSource, Data Binding ,MVVM , you can use WPF as you use WinForms but thats not how it is meant to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code

```
 var panel = new WrapPanel() { Height = 39 };
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Width = 93, Margin = new Thickness(-1, 5, 0, 0) });
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Width = 76, Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) });
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Width = 70, Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) });
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Width = 70, Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) });
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Width = 127, Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) });
            panel.Children.Add(new TextBox() { Width = 100, Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0) });
            this.Content = panel;
```

Comment: Thanks,was about to try that. But you did it faster. Thanks works perfectly

Comment: How do i set height auto or text wrapping

Comment: Remove the WrapPanel Height will internally treat as auto

Comment: There is one property called TextWrapping for TextBox, you can use it,

Comment: How do i provide name to Controls and use that name to perform function