# How to specify where to add xaml controls in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create some XAML -controls dynamically. I think I know how I could add the "stuff" itself, but I don't know, how to add it to specified location.

Here is a sample of the xaml -file (toolStencils.xaml):

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="colorTemplate" StartPoint="0.6,0" EndPoint="0,1" Opacity="1">
    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.01" />
        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.5" />
        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!-- ToolTemplate -->
        <Grid IsHitTestVisible="False" ToolTip="Tool 1">
            <Path Stretch="Fill" IsHitTestVisible="False"
                  StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                  Fill="{StaticResource colorTemplate}"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="0.2"
                  Data="M 0,0 H60 V60 H0 Z">
                <s:ToolItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Path Fill="Transparent" Stretch="Fill" Data="M 0,0 H60 V50 H0 Z"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </s:ToolItem.Template>
            </Path>
            <Grid Margin="2">
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Top"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Content="Tool number 1"
                       FontSize="10">
                    <Label.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Label.Resources>
                </Label>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>


<s:Toolbox x:Key="Tools" ItemSize="80,75">
    <ItemsControl.Items x:Uid="itemControls">



        <!-- Tool 1 -->
        <!-- ........... -->

    </ItemsControl.Items>
</s:Toolbox>
```

Now, I want to add more "Tools" dynamically. (worker.cs)

```
  // Load the resource dictionary

            var rd = new System.Windows.ResourceDictionary();
            rd.Source = new System.Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApplication;component/FirstFolder/SecondFolder/MyXamlFile.xaml", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

            // 
            if () // Do something
            {
               // Build and add same kind of tools than listed in xaml file
               // Grid grid = new Grid();
               // etc...
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Couldn't add tools.");
            }
```

How do I add all the things inside the `<ItemsControl.Items>`?  And then, if I add, for instance, Grid, how do I define, which things to add inside it, and which things not?

I have looked and tried for example [WPF: Add controls from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990624/wpf-add-controls-from-code) and [Adding WPF Controls](https://arcanecode.com/2007/09/07/adding-wpf-controls-progrrammatically/).

The problem is, that I have separated .xaml -file and .cs -file. So I can't straight refer to names or keys.

I hope you can get even slightly my point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use a template. Don't waste your time fighting the framework.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, that I have separated .xaml -file and .cs -file. So I can't straight refer to names or keys.

You will obviously need to get a reference to the view or some shared item (view model) otherwise you won't be able to do this cleanly.

I would suggest you change your ItemsContainer to bind to a List of controls specified in the view model (I'm assuming you have one):

```
<ItemsControl.Items x:Uid="itemControls" ItemsSource="{Binding DynamicControls}">
```

In your worker you'll need to pass a reference to the view model then in code you can do:

```
        if () // Do something
        {
           Grid grid = new Grid();
           // populate grid
           myViewModel.DynamicControls.Add(grid);
        }
```

You will need to ensure that a property changed notification is raised when an item is added so the view refreshes. The best way to do this is to make the  DynamicControls property an observable collection.

Here is a working dirty sample I made directly on the back of the view so you can see it working.

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFDynamicControls.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFDynamicControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" >
    <StackPanel>
        <Label>My Application</Label>
        <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Add Control</Button>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyControls}">

        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.MyControls = new ObservableCollection<Control>();
        this.DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Control> MyControls { get; set; }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyControls.Add(new Button() { Content = "New Button" });
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I see that is unclear, where those Controls are coming from. I have an xml -file, I read it first, and based on that, I want to create "Tools". So basically, whenever a "Tool" is found from xml -file, it will be created to xaml -file. That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I didn't quite get what you meant. So I should first create a list of "Tools" that I want to add. And then bind that list to ItemsControl.Items ?

Comment: Yeah that would work, if you create the list before the binding and don't expect it to change you can be lazy and not worry about the the change notifications too.

Comment: Okay. The problem is, that the list could change at some point... So I have to do the property changed notifications?

Comment: Yep, the best way is to use an ObservableCollection

Comment: I've added a working code sample, if you're not familiar with MVVM/bindings I suggest you do some reading on that as it will solve your problem of separated XAML and code.

Comment: Thanks, for the tips. I have done the ObservableCollection, and I can add there the info I want/need. Right now I'm trying to figure out, how (where to place and what to notify) to make proper PropertyChanged notifications to get the view updated, when an item is added to collection. Reading, searching and learning all the time :)